# Why would Visual Studio give access denied, code 5 error when trying to build solution with NuGet packages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to build a Visual Studio solution that references NuGet packages. I've copied the solution from someone else's computer (via Git, but I don't know if the means of copying is important here). I keep getting this command when I try to build the solution:

```
Error 3 The command ""D:\Custom Work\MySolution\Project\.nuget\nuget.exe" install
    "D:\Custom Work\MySolution\Project\AAIA.Model\packages.config" -source ""
    -RequireConsent -o "D:\Custom Work\MySolution\Project\packages"" exited with code 5.
    Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
```

I've checked the permissions on all the folders, and they all seem to be fine. No sharing violations either; Visual Studio 2010 is the only program that is touching these files and folders. Why would this be happening?

Comment: Thanks for all the alternate answers, guys -- I see that someone else's answer is voted higher than mine. How does one deal with multiple correct answers?

Comment: Off topic, but the general rule is that you check out the answer with the most votes vs the answer that was accepted.  You then make your choice on which one pertains to you.  Standard SO usage.

Comment: Thanks for the meta info. So based on what you're saying, I guess as the question asker, my role is to just leave the one that I originally accepted as the accepted answer, and let readers make their own decisions about what to read?

Comment: I'm not sure.  You might want to ask a question like this on meta.stackoverflow.com. You can always point your query back to this original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that's denying access to NuGet here is a Visual Studio configuration setting.

1. In VS, Go to **Tools > Options**.
2. Scroll down to the **Package Manager** node.
3. Make sure **Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build** is checked.
4. Click **OK**.
5. Try to rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 25):

Your cloning solution may not be passing in windows 'execute' permission for the nuget.exe file.

If you are cloning using git clone in cygwin, then attempting to use visual studio to open and build, the permission will not have been properly set for nuget.exe. The 'linux' of it doesn't support windows' executable permission. If you clone using something like git-extensions you can avoid this problem since its built for windows and supports the executable permission.

Comment: I was about to give up, quit my job, and check myself into an asylum. Then I saw this post. Thanks, +1

Comment: Same exact problem for me too. I cloned with SourceTree instead and the problem automagically went away.

Comment: Actually Cygwin and others handle Windows permissions just fine AFAICT, and so do the official git commands even when running in that environment. The *real* reason seems to be that the blobs aren't marked as executable in the repository itself and that some cloning solutions instead do set them as executables even if they're not (supposedly by mistake). The maintainers thus remain oblivious to the issue if they all use the same tools even if the tools seem wrong. [Light background](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35431849).

Comment: A "chmod +x nuget.exe" will fix it. No need to forsake git clone in cygwin.

Comment: True, but I'm guessing that a lot of people who are new to using git + cygwin in windows without much prior Linux experience aren't ready to really wrap their head around the problem (or have the time with deadlines and such).  I was like this at the time I wrote my answer.  I understand the problem now much more fully that I did.

Answer (score 19):

Or in my case the `<solution root>\.nuget\nuget.exe` file got corrupted.

1. Delete the `<solution root>\.nuget\nuget.exe` file
2. (re)enable NuGet package restore (VS2012 menu => "project" => enable nuget package restore)

Comment: Mine was the same case. I simply deleted corrupt nuget.exe and copied it from another project. Boom

Comment: I was having trouble doing a `git pull` from powershell, so I did it in cygwin. I was able to just delete the nuget.exe file, then do a `git checkout .nuget\NuGet.exe` from powershell, which did work! I know, I know, I shouldn't store .exe in source control. So sue me. :)

Comment: Perfect solution

Comment: Helped me as well. My nuget.exe had size of 0kb

Answer (score 7):

The executable bit issue has nothing to do with Cygwin, Linux or else.

### All you need to know in theory

Both Windows and Linux (and all Unixen) have a concept of executable program files which are flagged as such on the filesystem. When git checks out a tree on the working space, it writes its blobs as files and sets their [permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions) according to their "mode" stored in the tree object.

The "mode" is based on [Unix modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29) but is [more limited](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), presumably in the interest of being portable (there are only three modes: normal file, executable file, and symbolic link). The Windows implementation will have no trouble using it to set [NTFS file permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) accordingly.

This should be the end of the story. Executables are marked executables in the git repository and are set as such on all user systems automatically.

### Visual Studio quirks

However, the VS team *apparently* decided to automatically set some (all?) newly checked-out files as executable even if they aren't marked as such in the repository. Sounds good in theory, many people forget or don't really understand the concept of "permissions".

*I say "apparently" because it seems related to inherited permissions. It could be that they had no real intent to do that and instead forgot to set the appropriate permissions themselves.*

In practice, this means *even more* people forget and remain oblivious as long as they're all using Visual Studio exclusively to manipulate repositories. Those who use any other tool (including the official git commands) won't be able to execute the programs out-of-the-box, and will mistakenly be told to use Visual Studio instead of *actually marking the file as executable* in the repository.

Inversely, there is seemingly no way to **not** have a file automatically set as executable when using VS to check them out of a repository.

There is some voodoo that prevents git from detecting the actual permissions when setup in this way. This likely has to do with permission inheritance and special permissions. Using File Explorer's Security pane for the file's Properties along with git's source code, you might be able to work out if this is a feature or a bug. (IMO, the point is moot as I believe the permissions in the working space should match those in the repository, which they do when using the official git commands.)

### Manipulating permissions manually

Using Windows' File Explorer, use the file Properties window and its Security pane. Using Cygwin or any other Unix-y environment, use `chmod`.

### The real fix for Visual Studio users

```sh
chmod +x .nuget/NuGet.exe
```

(Alternatively use File Explorer to properly set the executable permission in such a way that git detects it -- as `chmod` does.)

git should detect the change and interpret it as a mode change. `git diff` yields:

```
diff --git a/.nuget/NuGet.exe b/.nuget/NuGet.exe
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Now **commit** it and push it upstream so that nobody else has to do it.

In the future, try to use the official `git clone` command instead or research this better in order to write a proper bug report to whoever can fix this in a sane way. It could be that both sides have things to do (git might need to get smarter about inherited permissions on Windows, and Visual Studio might need to be more careful when setting them on checkout).

Comment: Thank you, that was just the case. I do have one extra bit of info that might tangle up this clean image of Cygwin: I gave everyone executable permissions on the file using Explorer, and this rightly did show up when using `git diff`, as you said. But the file still was not executable! It was only after doing `chmod +x ../tools/nuget.exe` I could actually execute the file. The `git diff` command showed nothing else than previously, but the result was quite different! Especially on shared servers this is not the first weird file system behavior Cygwin has given me. It often messes up groups.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that your `.nuget\nuget.exe` file has executable permissions. By copying you might have changed ownership or permissions.